# What method gets executed when the application resumes from the background

Tags: iphone, objective-c, cocoa-touch

I need to know the method that gets executed when;

1.) the application resumes from the background (if we send the application to the background, and later when we resume the application from background)

2.) while using the application, the screen gets locked, and then we have to slide the lock screen slider to get in to the app. What is the method executed then.

Comment: Check the documentation here: https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/#DOCUMENTATION/iPhone/Conceptual/iPhoneOSProgrammingGuide/ManagingYourApplicationsFlow/ManagingYourApplicationsFlow.html

Answer (score 12, accepted):

I think this flow diagram make it very easy for you understand all your questions. Hope it helps..

**Courtesy:** http://www.cocoanetics.com/files/UIApplication_Delegate_post_4_v122.pdf

[image]

Comment: Thanks..For that. Actually I found that from iPhone developer chat room. http://stackoverflow.com/users/542425/0x8badf00d this fellow posted the link.. Credit goes to him.. :-)