# What is the launch sequence of an iOS app?

Tags: iphone, ios, objective-c

As the title indicates, what is the launch sequence of an iOS app when the user press the icon to start it, and when are the binary source of my own customized classes loaded into memory during this launch sequence, and loaded by which objects in the OS?

Comment: possible duplicate of [What method gets executed when the application resumes from the background](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/9509363/what-method-gets-executed-when-the-application-resumes-from-the-background)

Answer (score 19, accepted):

Launching an app into the foreground :-

[image]

Launching an app into the background :-

[image]

Change of App State in iOS :-

[image]

You can also refer to apple developer [Apple developer guideline for Application launching](https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/documentation/iPhone/Conceptual/iPhoneOSProgrammingGuide/StrategiesforHandlingAppStateTransitions/StrategiesforHandlingAppStateTransitions.html)

Comment: +1 too. But what do you call "Launching an App in Background" ?

Comment: new link at Apple about this topic: https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/documentation/iPhone/Conceptual/iPhoneOSProgrammingGuide/StrategiesforHandlingAppStateTransitions/StrategiesforHandlingAppStateTransitions.html