# At which point the launch image is presented/removed in iOS app startup sequence

Tags: ios, iphone, sprite-kit, preloader

There are many iOS games where you can see that first is shown launch image, and then after certain amount of time, the preloader is added. Just after about a second, or maybe even two, and that is a noticeable delay. I was wondering why is that, and I am thinking that something like this is happening:

- launch image is shown because view is not ready yet
- now, about second or two later, the view is ready, launch image is removed, scene is initialized
- then, preloader is added to the scene (or this is done directly in view controller) and after resources are loaded, the completition handler is called which removes preloader, and user now can use the interface

And because of the part while view is being initialized, the preloader can't be shown immediately right when a launch image is shown ? But if there is no view object yet, how is launch image shown? I think I am missing something...

So, the question is, at which point the launch image is presented/removed in app startup sequence exactly ? After which event/method execution?  I suppose its removed after something like -viewWillAppear is executed for the first time? I hope this make some sense..

Answer (score 1):

Your app's launch image is displayed as soon as your launch your app. Hence the name. It is removed when the appDelegate appDidFinishLaunching: method runs.

If you want to manually set a longer display time for your launch image, you can add this code to the appDidFinishLaunching: method

```
sleep(4);
```

4 being the number of seconds.

Comment: I understand...But if I block main thread for few seconds, with something like NSDate *date = [[NSDate alloc] init];while ([date timeIntervalSinceNow] > -3) {} inside viewWillAppear then appDidFinishLaunching is called but launch image is still presented for those few seconds. Do you have any idea why is that?

Comment: @Whirlwind - No idea. It's not good practice to block the main thread so I am uncertain what your end goal is here. If you are just looking for an app's life cycle, you can check out this previous SO question http://stackoverflow.com/questions/17366107/what-is-the-launch-sequence-of-an-ios-app and also look at this doc from Apple https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/documentation/iPhone/Conceptual/iPhoneOSProgrammingGuide/TheAppLifeCycle/TheAppLifeCycle.html

Comment: I just tried to find a way to simulate long running task, nothing more ... Just for testing purposes, because I was too lazy to simulate real situation which blocking main thread for the moment, like initializing huge amount of real game assets... :)